# Installing Tar file

Tags: server, mail

I have downloaded the iredmail tar file iRedMail-0.9.9.tar.bz2, and placed it ia a folder named iRedMail. Can some one give ma step-by-step instruction how I install it on Ubuntu 18.04? I will very much appreciate help from an expert.

Answer (score 0):

The install instructions for Ubuntu are found [here.](https://docs.iredmail.org/install.iredmail.on.debian.ubuntu.html)
to extract the file you go to the folder you extracted in and type the command from a terminal `tar -xvjf <file>.tar.bz2` replace  with correct name. It will extract the file in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the step by step guide for installation and also the setup here.
Click [here](https://kifarunix.com/how-to-setup-iredmail-mail-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)!

after downloading the tar file you can extract the file using the command

```
tar xjf iRedMail-0.9.9.tar.bz2
```

and this will generates the directory containing all the files .
change your directory into that directory and you can add and modify the configurations in the `iRedMail.sh` file .

Comment: Consider adding more details to your answer before including the link for further assistance.